# Reload a script jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load, reload

I have a problem

I have a script in my page that do some stuff like deleting a row from a table, add a row 
in a table by jquery ajax.

But when I add with ajax a new row/s this row/s don't work.

So there is a method that I can re-load this script every N second ?!?

```
 <script>
  .... some stuff ....
 setInterval(function() {
  #reload script or something like that
 },2000);
 </script>
```

For example this function on click open a message...

HTML

```
  <table>

  <tr class='MessageList' id='a_1'><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr class='MessageList' id='a_2'><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr class='MessageList' id='a_3'><td>3</td></tr>
  </table>
```

JS

```
        $('.MessageList').click(function(){
    var id=this.id;
    if(openMessage)
    {
        if($('#read-message').attr('message')==$('#'+id).attr('data'))
        {
            $('#message-list').addClass('hide');
            $('#read-message').removeClass('hide');
        }
        else
        {
        var readMsg=true;
        if($('#'+id).hasClass('not_viewed'))
        {
            readMsg=false;
            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo AJAX_RE;?>/nvinbox/",
            data: "b=" + $('#'+id).attr('view') + "&a=<?php echo $_SESSION['registrar']['inbox'] ?>",
            cache: true,
            async: false,
            error: function(){
            wAlert({ title: "<?php echo $this->languages["PLEASE_TRY_LATER"] ?>",description: "<?php echo $this->languages["SOMETHING_WRONG"] ?>",redirect:'<?php echo USER_REGISTRAR_PAGE?>inbox/'});
            },      
            success: function (response) {
                if(response!='No direct script access allowed')
                {
                    var arr = id.split("_");
                    $('#message_'+arr[1]).addClass('viewed').removeClass('not_viewed');
                    readMsg=true;
                }
                else wAlert({ title: "<?php echo $this->languages["PLEASE_TRY_LATER"] ?>",description: "<?php echo $this->languages["SOMETHING_WRONG"] ?>"});
            }
            });
        }
        if(readMsg)
        {
            jQuery.ajax({type: "POST",url: "<?php echo AJAX_RE;?>/upinbox/",dataType : "json",
            success: function (response) {
            $('#notifMessage').remove();
            $('#messageInbox').append(response[0]);
            if(response[1]!=0){}
            }});

            $('#read-message').remove();
            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo AJAX_RE;?>/vinbox/",
            data: "c="+id+"&b=" + $('#'+id).attr('data') + "&a=<?php echo $_SESSION['registrar']['inbox'] ?>",
            cache: true,
            async: false,
            error: function(){
            wAlert({ title: "<?php echo $this->languages["PLEASE_TRY_LATER"] ?>",description: "<?php echo $this->languages["SOMETHING_WRONG"] ?>",redirect:'<?php echo USER_REGISTRAR_PAGE?>inbox/'});
            },      
            success: function (response) {
                if(response!='No direct script access allowed')
                {
                    var arr = id.split("_");
                    $('.email-content').append(response);
                    $('#message-list').addClass("hide");
                    $('#read-message').removeClass("hide");
                }
                else wAlert({ title: "<?php echo $this->languages["PLEASE_TRY_LATER"] ?>",description: "<?php echo $this->languages["SOMETHING_WRONG"] ?>"});
            }
            });
        }
    }
    }
    else openMessage=true;
});
```

When i ADD a new row in the table

```
  <table>
  <!-- new row HERE -> <tr class='MessageList' id='a_1456'><td>1456</td></tr>

  <tr class='MessageList' id='a_1'><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr class='MessageList' id='a_2'><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr class='MessageList' id='a_3'><td>3</td></tr>
  </table>
```

If I click new row tr don't work...but the other work fine...

Comment: This sounds more like you try to solve it the wrong way. You should describe what is not working if you add new rows and show the corresponding code. (e.g. the event handlers not work for new elements).

Comment: This pretty much sounds like you need to use event delegation: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events for enabling you to bind hanndlers to non-existent elements.

Comment: We will also need more information if we are to help you, along with a better description of the problem.

Comment: The `$('.MessageList').click(` only applies the click callbacks to the elements that are in the DOM at the time you execute the code. Like _m90_ said you should look at event delegation which would look this way: `$(document).on('click', '.MessageList', `, that means for each click that happens on document, check if the clicked element matches the selector `.MessageList`